# Is there something like List.init, but of the form "int -> 'T -> 'T list" instead?

Tags: .net, f#

I am looking for a way to try to simplify the following expression, which looks ugly, IMO:

```
List.map (fun _ -> generateIndividual()) [1..popSize]
```

I found about `List.init`, but it still isn't really what I am looking for:

```
List.init popSize (fun x -> generateIndividual())
```

It'd be perfect gave it not an argument to the lambda expression. It'd be perfect this way:

```
List.init popSize generateIndividual()
```

Is there something in the F# library that'd help me clean this up?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: You do want the `generateIndividual()` function to be called only once, right? Otherwise what you want is not possible in a strict language without wrapping it in a function.

Comment: I want it to be called for each element of the list (it'll generate a random number!)

Comment: Then what you want is impossible. If you do `f x (g())`, `g()` will be called exactly once, no matter what `f` is. Those are simply the rules of the language. The version using `init` and the anonymous function, is the closest you'll be able to get to what you want.

Comment: I wonder why you got a downvote... I gave you an upvote to balance it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
[ for i = 1 to popSize do 
      yield generateIndividual() ]
```

Comment: Although I like Ankur's answer I would say Jon's the good answer. By defining let generateIndividual _ = ..., you can still call it like so elsewhere in your code generateIndividual().

Comment: In case you don't have control over generateIndividual function (it may be from other library) then the best option is the list comprehension solution which in general better than modifying the function signature

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the fact that unit(void) is also a type you can do this:

```
List.init popSize (ignore >> generateIndividual)
```

Answer (score 5):

Not really. The nearest solution would be to alter the definition of your `generateIndividual` function so that it accepts a value of any type (rather than just the value of the type `unit`) and discards it:

```
let generateIndividual _ = ...
```

Then you could write:

```
List.init popSize generateIndividual
```

Another solution is to use a list comprehension:

```
[for _ in 1..popSize -> generateIndividual()]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
let generateIndividual dummy = 4
let popSize = 10
let lst = List.init popSize generateIndividual
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension like this:

```
module List =
    let init2 count f = List.init count (fun _ -> f())
```

You can then call it like this:

```
List.init2 5 generateIndividual
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, late and all, but:

1. This solution is as short as you'll get,
2. Unlike ebb's (which you've chosen), this one will execute side-effects once:

   `(fun a -> Array.create a >> List.ofArray)`

The type is exactly (int -> 'a -> 'a list), only disadvantage is conversion from Array to List, but this is still a bit better performance-wise than converting Seq to List (which is what done by list expressions).